# Cefsharp succesive calls to Load Method

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

Please somebody could give a hint about this question?  I have the following need, I am using CefSharp (Winforms) to show some web pages, but need these ones be shown only during some time e.g. 30 seconds and then to show the next one. This  code is not working, since it seems the Thread.Sleep locks the execution:

```
InitializeChromium();
chromeBrowser.Load("http://www.google.com");
Thread.Sleep(30000);
chromeBrowser.Load("http://www.facebook.com");
```

Is there some other way to get the behavior I want?

Regards

Comment: Use a Timer if you need to perform an action at a set interval.

Comment: With `Thread.Sleep()` you're blocking the current Thread, which is the UI Thread, in this case. So your UI is blocked as well. Add those URLs to a `List<string>` (or a similar collection) and use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to increment an `int` Field that points to the URL in the list to pass to the `chromeBrowser.Load();` method. If you reach the last index in the List, you can reset the Field to `0` and start over (eventually).

Comment: thank you for your answers, I got it using timers.